# Access Azure DevOps Artifact Feed from different organization

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

We have created a package in our company's Azure DevOps organization; it is uploaded as an artifact and can be used in pipelines in the same organization. This all works perfectly.

We now want to use the same package in a narrow, clearly defined set of other organizations. But when we try to access the package from within a pipeline of another organization, we receive an error message: The package is not found.

How can we give other "organizations" in Azure DevOps access to the package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can we give other "organizations" in Azure DevOps access to the package?

You can use service connections to do that. The service connection type you need to choose depends on the type of your package.

Here is an example of getting access to a universal package from another organization.

Step1:

Go to Project Settings -> Pipelines/Service connections -> New service connection -> Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server -> Next.

Connect this project to the organization of the package.

Step2:

If you are using Classic UI pipeline, add a built-in task 'Universal packages'. Choose 'Another organization/collection' in 'Feed location'. Choose the connection you created in step1 and fill in information of the feed.

If you are using YAML, add the following task:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal download'
  inputs:
    feedsToUse: external
    externalFeedCredentials: {service connection}
    # if you are using project-scoped feed, replace {feed} with {project/feed}
    feedDownloadExternal: {feed}
    packageDownloadExternal: {package}
    versionDownloadExternal: {version number}
```

**If you want to connect to a Npm/Nuget/Maven/... package**, you need to create a correspondant service connection and use Feed URL instead of organization URL. Then in pipeline, you need to run an authenticate task (you can find it in built-in task list) before using the package. Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#common-service-connection-types) for detailed information.

Comment: I have been fighting this battle for 3 years on a half-dozen DevOps organizations and still have never gotten it to work. I ALWAYS get the error "Cannot find the package...". I have tried every possible combination of the names of my packages and nothing has worked. Please tell me EXACTLY what to put in for the name of the package, like EXACTLY the location in the other project's artifact feed where I can find this EXACT name to put in. I have been getting project files from other feeds into VS and CLI for years but have never gotten Azure Pipelines tasks to download them.